# Как вывести символы из массива в lineEdit qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть буквенный массив и нужно из него вывести поочереди букву в lineEdit. 
ui->lineEdit->setText(); если выводить с помощью setText то буквы будут поочереди заменять друг друга а мне нужно что бы они записывались друг за другом как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить букву 'A':

```
 lineEdit->setText(lineEdit->text() + 'A');
```