# Как вывести из массива по очереди символы в lineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

Допустим есть массив `char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}` и есть `LineEdit` и нужно из массива по очереди вывести буквы из массива. Есть счётчик for `(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { /* и здесь нужно вывести эти буквы */ }` если использовать `ui->lineEdit->setText();` то будет выводится последняя буква а мне нужно что бы выводились все. Как это сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести символы из массива в lineEdit qt?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929764/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-lineedit-qt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->Text() + arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

если внутри счётчика нет принудительной обработки цикла событий (вызовов типа qApp->processEvents()), то процесса последовательного добавления вы не увидите и в этом случае лучше вывести эту строку без цикла:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::fromLatin1(arr,sizeof(arr)));
```